Vue, computed, i18n and quotes
I have a project that has reactive translation of PT/EN, using 2 JSON files, i18n and computed().
All parts of the project work well, but in my file route.js all of my translations are shown with quotes "".
Example of json:
"appName": {
  "home": "Home"
}

In other pages it shows like: Home

But in header that is defined by my router.js it shows like: "Home"
This is my router file:
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import i18n from '@/locales/index'
import { computed } from 'vue'

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      component: () => import('@/views/layout/Layout.vue'),
      meta: { requiresAuth: true },
      children: [
        {
          path: '',
          component: () => import('@/views/home/Home.vue'),
          meta: {
            requiresAuth: true,
            subtitle: computed(() => i18n.global.t('home.subtitle.home')),
            appName: computed(() => i18n.global.t('layout.appName.wos')),
            helloUserMensage: true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
})

I've already tried using a replace function to remove the quotation marks, but it didn't work. If I remove the computed function the quotes are gone, but I lose the reactive translation.

I see no reasons for this to happen. The way you use "meta" could contribute to the problem. Please, provide a way to reproduce, currently only you can debug this. To narrow the problem down, you can start with returning static "Home" string from a computed instead of t() and assigning t() to local variable inside a computed and checking its value with a debugger.
